# dropzonejs opening modal box when upload completed

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, dropzone.js

I am using dropzonejs in my asp.net mvc5 application. I am trying to an application, when a user drag a file to dropzone,open a modal box and want him to fill the form which is related the file. And i want to insert these information to the database.

I am using bootstrap modal box.

How can i do this ? Where should i start?

In which method should i need to open dialog box? Complete function ?

```
myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
  //Open Modal Box
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    Dropzone.options.dropzoneJsForm = {

        //prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
        autoProcessQueue: true,

        init: function () {
            var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all");
            var myDropzone = this; //closure

            submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {

                myDropzone.processQueue();
            });
            myDropzone.on("complete", function (file) {
                $('#myModal').modal('show')
            });

        }
    };

</script>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                asdasdsadsd
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me